# error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"?

Tags: java, uri, illegalargumentexception, file-uri

I am receiving the following error when trying to access font file :

```
011.08.31 12:12:42.704 ERROR [PDFOutputHandler] - Unable to resolve Unicode font
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:366)
at com.xx.reports.output.handler.PDFOutputHandler.addUnicodeFont(PDFOutputHandler.java:393)
at com.xx.reports.output.handler.PDFOutputHandler.renderOutput(PDFOutputHandler.java:104)
at com.xx.reports.output.handler.PDFOutputHandler.renderOutput(PDFOutputHandler.java:134)
at com.xx.reports.output.appender.PdfAppender.renderOutput(PdfAppender.java:103)
at com.xx.reports.servlet.BasePdfOutputServlet.setResponsePdf(BasePdfOutputServlet.java:53)
at com.xx.reports.servlet.JSPToPDFServlet.execute(JSPToPDFServlet.java:115)
at com.xx.reports.servlet.JSPToPDFServlet.doGet(JSPToPDFServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
```

Please find below my code:

```
   try
    {
    if (unicodeFontPath == null)
    {
    URI fontClassURI = new URI(this.getClass().getResource("/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF").toString());
    unicodeFontPath = new File(fontClassURI).getAbsolutePath();
    }
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(unicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    logger.error("Unable to resolve Unicode font", e);
    }
```

PLease suggest what could be the issue. I am out of ideas.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: try adding `file:///` to the beginning of `/fonts/ARIALUNO.TTF`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You get that exception, because you are using `new File(myURI)` constructor, while `myURI` has differet schema than `file:`.

For example, this will **work** (note **file:**//...):

```
System.out.println(new File(new URI("file:///etc/passwd")));
```

while this will **not work** (note **http:**//...):

```
System.out.println(new File(new URI("http://localhost/etc/passwd")));
```

If you want to use `getResource()` method, then you have to operate on URL. You cannot assume it will always have "file:" schema.

If you need to create Font from resource *.ttf file, you can do:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```