# How do I list file names on a server in a directory?

Tags: java, file, web, directory

I am trying to get the names of all the directories and files that inside the `tpo` directory on some server but
as I run the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        File file = new File(new URI("http://xxx/tpo/"));
        String list[] = file.list();
        for(String name : list) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

I get the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:366)
at hack.List.main(List.java:17)
```

Why is that ? How do I get the file names and the names of the directories inside the `tpo` directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843557/uri-scheme-is-not-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296052/error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-uri-scheme-is-not-file

Comment: You have to connect to the server using FTP, SSH or similar. You can not just list the files of a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The webserver gives you an html page that contains a list of files if he wants to. If he doesn't, then you have to login via FTP into the server. The error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
```

Says exactly what is wrong. `java.io.File` is meant for offline files on your local harddrives/usb devices.

Comment: what if the FTP server is not running ? There could be a possibility that FTP server is not running

Comment: Of course that is possible. Do you own the server or not. If not, you are most likely not going to be able to do what you want.

Comment: No I don't own the server. Is there any way I can check if FTP server is running on that server?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you get the wrong point.You may try to return a list that containing the file name in the remote server.Then you can do anything with the file name.

Such as:

```
return new File("xxx").listFiles();
```

Then you receive the list,do anything you want.